# Print bytes of data label (artificial) array as hex and dec in ARM gdb

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, gdb

I have got 3 Arrays under the data label `(ArrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC)`, each having 16 bytes.
I've already written the program that goes through it row by row and adds each row of `A` with each row of B and then saves the result to the same row of array `C`.

I want to add a breakpoint just before the program stops executing and then print the memory from `[=ArrayC]` up to `[=ArrayC] + 15`, byte by byte, once in hex and once in decimal.

How is that possible?

Comment: `x/128xb ArrayC` or similar. See `help x`. Note that `16*3=48`, no idea why you want `128`. Also `128 != 0x128` and offsets start from zero.

Comment: With a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x/16xb &ArrayC for hexadecimal and
x/16ub &ArrayC for decimal